# Regex extract first portion of four numbers starting from specific position

Tags: regex

How do i extract four numbers starting after the 8th number `which is dynamic` from the following strings using regex.

```
20190715171712904_10008_file_activate_10.20.30.4000233223456_name.unl 

20190715141712904_10008_runco_activate_10.20.30.40_name.unl
```

From first string i want 1717

From second string i want 1417

I have tried to write regex queries in https://regex101.com/ i.e.

I have tried  `^\d{8}([0-9]{4})$` but not working.

Comment: remove the `$` at the end

Comment: put .* at last . $ indicates end of regex expression matching  string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `$`. It forces the expression to look for the end of the string after your 4 digits, which it is not. The answer will be in the first subgroup capture. Note you can use `\d` for the second `[0-9]` as well.

If your language supports look-behinds, you can capture your digits as the main capture, instead of a subgroup:

```
(?<=^\d{8})\d{4}
```

This is really not a problem for a regular expression though - getting the substring indexed from index 4 to index 7 including (0 indexed) is basic and faster in any language.

Comment: Works okay, You know any other way without  look-behinds?

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa Yes, what you posted without the `$`. It's in the answer. The result will be in the first subgroup match.

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa another thought that occurred to me - probably beneficial to not use regex at all - added that as well.

Comment: What other expression would you use if not regex.? the system that i use has a regex box for filtering, thats why i use it